# Creating an extremely detailed user Journey Map

Tags: user-journey, journey-map, service-design

I'm about to start work on a detailed customer journey map for a travel company. This to be for an end to end service and there are a LOT of touch points.
I'm just curious has anyone any tips/feedback on working with extremely detailed journey maps that they could share?

For instance, lets say I have several main groupings:

Plan |
Purchase |
Departure |
Trip |
Return |
Next Trip |

Each of these consisting of many potential touch points online and offline.
Can anyone reccommend best practice with regards to creating and editing a journey map for an experience that has the potential to be vast.
Would you break it out into groups - would that mean you would lose an element of that holistic view?

Also if mapping different things across the journey (x-axis), 
e.g.

- current customer experience (scope, touchpoints and performance
- areas where competitors compete (and analysis)
- identify areas of experience where other companies (non-competitors) provide value
- future experience roadmap (vehicle for storytelling)

How would you represent all these different dimensions without making it overly complex? Would it be a case of producing multiple versions of the map - which in turn means more management/upkeep?

Just curious to hear of other people's experience's with this. What's worked for them and what hasn't.

Comment: One idea is to make the journey in the shoes with different characteristics (personas). For example **the extreme planner**, **the "best price chaser"**, **the impulsive buyer**, etc to cover in the target group.. and try and map out how each type of user perceives each step in the purchase flow and from there formulate what design tweaks should be done to improve overall UX.

Comment: I maybe stating the obvious but for starting ideas, take a look at current apps/websites that are similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a complicated set of information to display on a map, I think the best approach is not to decide for the user which information to show.  Instead, make sure you capture all the categories and attributes that users might care about, and let the users filter the map based on these things.

If you try to make a one-size-fits-all view, you will be caught between the traps of either making the display too busy on the one hand, or hiding information some users care about on the other.